# how to develop an add-in for visio

Tags: icons, add-in, visio, bpmn

I want to create an add-in to visio so that I can draw BPMN diagrams (Business Process Modeling Notation). A similar work is available here: http://www.interfacing.com/free-visio-bpmn-modeler. But I want to create my own icons(notations) and make it domain specific. Please help me? How can I do this? What languages do I have to use?

Comment: Hello Nilani! How where you able to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can develop add-ins for Visio using the Visio SDK. There are several versions, of which the [2010 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758690.aspx) is the most recent. It contains samples written in C#, VB.NET, C++, and even classic VB. The best place to start learning about developing for Visio would be the [Visio Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905478.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just download the Visio add-in. Visio allows you to create your own shapes so you can customize the shapes provided.
With Visio 2007, they introduced a rules feature so you can embellish the addin with custom rules.