# Add-in for Visio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, visio

I require assistance for the following

I would like to create an add-in for Microsoft Visio 2010 to zoom individual shapes. To achieve this I would like to create a TreeView (using  Visual Studio 2010). From this control, based on the selection, either zoom the entire diagram or individual shapes.

I have tried custom task panes but its not possible for Visio to extend custom task panes.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I've done an addin for Visio, but you may have luck checking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/gg553002.aspx). Go down where it says "Managed Code".

Here is some more info: [Overview of Add-ons and COM Add-ins in Visio 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851468%28office.12%29.aspx)

and another related answer: [how to develop an add-in for visio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699850/how-to-develop-an-add-in-for-visio)